# Adding and image beside a spinner in an android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I just want to add an image beside the `Spinner` in my layout. I tried `align:layout_gravity = "right"` for the image, but this moved the image to the right side in the layout and below the `Spinner` present in the same layout. What I want is for the image to be displayed exactly besides the `Spinner`. Below is the xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/headingBgColor"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Group"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5sp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBlockLog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tasks"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBlockLog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Messages"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBlockLog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Groups"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBlockLog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notes"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBlockLog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyProfile"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/centerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/contacts" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/centerLqayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10sp" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SMS"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBlockLog1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_15" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

`LinearLayout` with orientation set to `vertical` will put the child views one below other. You have two options:

- You either wrap the `Spinner` and the `ImageView` in another `LinearLayout` with orientation set to `horizontal` so the two views end up on the same line.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dip" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/contacts" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- You use a layout that allows the children to be placed relative to others(like a `RelativeLayout`) instead of the parent `LinearLayout` with the id `centerLayout`.

Comment: ya thank u very much i used another linear layout with orientation vertical and i got exactly what i want. thanks luksprog.

Comment: I dint got the concept here. What output is generating? in my case, the spinner and image are far away from each other. Is there any specific solution to make image onto the right side of spinner??

Comment: @nick You should ask your own question providing more details about your situation, especially the layout file that you used.